# What is the zhuyin for the onomatopoei bia1

Tags: pinyin, onomatopoeia

[image]

Seeing that my existing code to map pinyin to zhuyin has no mapping for **biā** ..

```
ao: "ㄠ",
ba: "ㄅㄚ",
bai: "ㄅㄞ",
ban: "ㄅㄢ",
bang: "ㄅㄤ",
bao: "ㄅㄠ",
bei: "ㄅㄟ",
ben: "ㄅㄣ",
beng: "ㄅㄥ",
bi: "ㄅㄧ",
bian: "ㄅㄧㄢ",
biao: "ㄅㄧㄠ",
bie: "ㄅㄧㄝ",
bin: "ㄅㄧㄣ",
bing: "ㄅㄧㄥ",
bo: "ㄅㄛ",
bu: "ㄅㄨ",
ca: "ㄘㄚ",
```

.. I'm just inclined to add the pinyin-to-zhuyin mapping below for **biā** onomatopeoeia

```
bia: "ㄅㄧㄧㄚ", // onomatopoeia, e.g., 吧 bia1, biā
```

Browser's speech synthesis cannot synthesize pinyin, however it can synthesize zhuyin instead:

```
{ 
    // Browser cannot synthesize this:
    //     new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("bia1");
    // nor this:
    //     new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("biā");

    // Can use zhuyin though:
    const utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("ㄅㄧㄧㄚ");
    utterance.voice = speechSynthesis.getVoices().find(e => e.lang === 'zh-CN');
    speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
}
```

And I also need the dictionary to give the correct zhuyin for **biā**

[image]

Is the **ㄅㄧㄧㄚ** the correct zhuyin for onomatopoeia **biā** ?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you inclined to use "ㄅㄧㄧㄚ" with two "ㄧ", instead of just "ㄅㄧㄚ"?

Comment: @Bettry ㄅㄧㄧㄚ sounds closer to **bia** onomatopoeia, ㄅㄧㄧㄚ is pronounced as bi-ia, bi-ya. While ㄅㄧㄚ is pronounced as bi-a, bi-ah. Sample sound here: https://jsfiddle.net/yLpf28ma/1/

It would be better though if there is a zhuyin exactly for **bia**, one syllable. But I think no one would dedicate a zhuyin symbol just for that, as **bia** is the only onomatopeia sound in Chinese that can't be mapped to existing zhuyin symbols

Comment: I don't think you can rely on speech synthesis for pronunciation in general, and certainly not for borderline non-standard syllables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Michael Buen I see where you're coming from.

However, please look at other characters that end with `-ia`:

- 加 jiā ㄐㄧㄚ
- 俩 liǎ ㄌㄧㄚˇ
- 掐 qiā ㄑㄧㄚ
- 虾 xiā ㄒㄧㄚ

It is pretty clear that `-ia` is just `ㄧㄚ` . There is no need to use two `ㄧ`. (Chinese phonology does not distinguish between `bi-ia` and `bi-a`.)

Therefore, `biā` should probably be `ㄅㄧㄚ`.

On a second note, I have never heard people say `吧` as `biā`. It is not in any of the major dictionaries, eg 新华字典, 现代汉语词典, 汉语大字典, etc. I think `biā` is one of the onomatopoeic words that do not have a character form. (Some other examples are `piā` and `duāng`.) You probably should not list it under `吧`.

Edit:

Your jsfiddle link sounds just like "ia" to me ("b" is not pronounced). Maybe something is wrong with the synthesizer on my computer. Then I played with Google Translate and understood your puzzle!

Google Translate plays "bia" like `bi-a`. I think what's happening is, Google Translate does not recognize "bia" as a legit syllable in Mandarin phonology, and is treating it as two characters instead of one. It's like it's saying "必啊". Of course, that is not the correct pronunciation of "bia".

Then again, it is even more unlikely for a synthesizer to play "ㄅㄧㄧㄚ" as one syllable. I don't know what you hear, but I suspect it is like "必呀", which is also not the correct pronunciation of "bia".

"bia" should be one syllable, just like the other examples I gave (加 jiā, 俩 liǎ, etc). If you want to learn its pronunciation, listen to the other examples and try to substitute the initial. But you really do not need to do so. As I've said, it is not in any major dictionary. It is borderline at best. A new learner does not need to learn that.

Comment: Thanks Betty, `bia1` is listed under `吧`. I'm just using an existing open-source dictionary CEDICT

example: https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=吧#:~:text=smack

example: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bsun94/ChineseDictionary/master/dict_db/cedict_ts.u8#:~:text=smack

Perhaps I'm just overthinking it, as the sound produced by the speech synthesizer API is `bi-a`/`bi-ah`, not `bi-ia`/`bi-ya`. Maybe it's just the flaw of the speech synthesizer API I'm using

Comment: @MichaelBuen I see. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks Betty for digging it further. The speech synthesizer I'm using plays `ㄅㄧㄚ`  more like `必啊` than `必呀`.   Yes "ㄅㄧㄧㄚ" will not be pronounced as one syllable too, but at least the `ya` sound is there, unlike `ㄅㄧㄚ` which totally sounds like `必啊`, at least to my ear / my computer. Anyway, both are wrong due to two-syllable sounds, `必呀` is less wrong than `必啊` though. If you will pronounce `bia` in a very slow manner, it is pronounced as `必呀`, not `必啊`.

Interesting enough, Google Translate's zhuyin speech synthesizer ignores `ㄅㄧㄚ`, while the rest plays correctly, e.g., `ㄐㄧㄚ` , `ㄑㄧㄚ`, `ㄒㄧㄚ`

Comment: Here's the link to Google's zhuyin speech synthesizer:

https://translate.google.com/?sl=zh-CN&tl=en&text=ㄐㄧㄚ%0Aㄅㄧㄚ%0Aㄑㄧㄚ%0Aㄒㄧㄚ

For what it's worth, here is how Google maps the pinyin `ia` to its hanzi counterpart:

https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=zh-CN&text=jia%0Aqia%0Axia%0Apia%0Abia&op=translate

Comment: @MichaelBuen If you speak really really quickly, both 必呀 and 必啊 will end up as `bia`. :)

Answer (score 0):

If there is such a pronunciation (which I don't recognize both the sound and the word uses), then I think its Zhuyin would be "ㄅㄧㄚ".

But my web search finds the pronunciation remains in "ba", "ㄅㄚ". You can listen to it on the page linked below.

[image]

[https://www.bing.com/search?q=meaning+of+貼吧](https://www.bing.com/search?q=meaning+of+%E8%B2%BC%E5%90%A7)

And this one as well:

[image]

[https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=吧](https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E5%90%A7)

Also,

[image]

[https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/吧](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%90%A7)